# Android TV Remote Control v2 invoke Voice Assistant

Tags: ios, android-tv, google-tv, remote-control

I'm developing a voice search function using the Android TV Remote Control v2 technology on iOS.
I can successfully connect to the smart TV and send commands, as well as modify text in input fields. However, I'm unable to invoke the voice assistant by sending the command with code - `KEYCODE_VOICE_ASSIST = 231`. As far as I understand, sending this command is not necessary, and instead, I need to send a **RemoteVoiceBegin** packet, which I'm already doing. However, the voice assistant still doesn't appear. In response, I receive a **RemoteVoicePayload** packet from the TV, which contains the sessionID value that I sent in the RemoteVoiceBegin packet. What am I doing wrong?